# Erro ao requisitar a ID de um dado no banco através do nome STRING do dado

Tags: java, web-service, android-studio, ksoap2

Bom galera, eu fiz um metodo no meu webservice para conseguir pegar a ID de um valor de um estado, ou seja, eu passo pra função um nome EX: "Acre" e ele me retorna o ID no banco desse estado. Fiz ela, funcionou legal testando pelo SOAPUI que é utilizado pra testar, escrevi "Acre" e ele me retornou 1, até ai tudo bem... Fui implementar no meu projeto.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String ObjetoDAO.Estado.toString()' on a null object reference                                                                                  at com.example.scartop.photoprint.frmCadastro.CadastroUsuario(frmCadastro.java:112)
```

Bom o meu metodo DAO que busca esse dado é:

```
  public Estado buscaIdEstadoPorNome(String nome){
    Estado est = null;

    SoapObject buscarIdEstado = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, BUSCAR_ID_ESTADO);

    buscarIdEstado.addProperty("nome", nome);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(buscarIdEstado);

    envelope.implicitTypes = true;

    HttpTransportSE http = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try {
        http.call("urn: " + BUSCAR_ID_ESTADO, envelope);
        SoapObject resposta = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
        est = new Estado();
        est.setID_ESTADO(Integer.parseInt(resposta.getProperty("ID_ESTADO").toString()));

    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return est;
}
```

E to usando isso para retornar o dado:

```
EstadoDAO estDao = new EstadoDAO();
    Estado est = estDao.buscaIdEstadoPorNome("Acre");
    Log.d("Id Estado: ", est.toString());
```

Alguem saberia me dizer o que está errado? e por que? Agradeço desde ja.

Comment: Talvez seu código esteja lançando alguma exceção e o catch está sendo executado, retornando assim null. Então, quando você tenta logar chamando o Log.d("Id Estado: ", est.toString()); ele lança um NullPointerException